# Erro in Castalia without logging in test

Tags: omnet++

I reinstalled Castalia as my storage burned. I followed the manual and after the end I went to carry out the rest in radioTest.
I called normally
`~/Castalia/Simulations/radioTest$ ../../bin/Castalia -c General`
but returned the following error:

> -bash: ../../bin/Castalia: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

If I run
`~/Castalia/Simulations/radioTest$ ../../CastaliaBin -c General`
I get the output:

> OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation (C) 1992-2014 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
> Version: 4.6, build: 141202-f785492, ...
> Setting up Cmdenv...
> Loading NED files from /home/andre/Castalia/src: 32
> Preparing for running configuration General, run #0...
> Scenario: $repetition=0
> Assigned runID=General-0-20220704-19:22:42-33
> Setting up network `SN'...
> Initializing...
> Running simulation...
> ** Event #1 T=0 Elapsed: 0.000s (0m 00s) 0% completed ev/sec=0
> ** Event #18140 T=100 Elapsed: 0.024s (0m 00s) 100% completed ev/sec=755792
> <!> Simulation time limit reached -- simulation stopped at event #18140, t=100.
> Display the content on the monitor
> Calling finish() at end of Run #0...
> Castalia| module:SN.node[0].ResourceManager
> Castalia| simple output name:Consumed Energy

However, it doesn't save any files or the log of `Castali-tracer.txt`.
I didn't find anything related to this. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it. My ubuntu was with python 3.10 and for some reason it didn't work. So I installed python version 2 and it ran normally